# Using fscanf in C

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to read from a file into array.
My file called Players.txt contains:

```
Del Piero|3|Italy|Juventus|
Ronaldo|0|Portugal|Real Madrit
```

I used `fscanf` , but it is not working correctly , I am not doing right the conversion.

can anyone help me to read and store them into arrays. Like the array player name to contain `{ Del Piero, Ronaldo}`

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define NUM_PLAYERS 20
#define NAME_LENGTH 100
#define COUNTRY_NAME 20

int main (void)

{
    FILE *Players;

    char player_name [NUM_PLAYERS][NAME_LENGTH] = {0};
    char country_name[NUM_PLAYERS][COUNTRY_NAME] = {0};
    char team_name[NUM_PLAYERS][NAME_LENGTH] = {0};
    int goals_scored[NUM_PLAYERS] = {0};
    int i;

    Players = fopen("G:\\COP2220\\Project 5\\Players.txt", "r");
    if (Players == NULL)
    {
        printf("File not found.\n");
    }
    else

    {

       while (fscanf(Players, " %[^|]s %[^|]d %[^|]s %[^|]s",player_name[i],&goals_scored[i],country_name[i],team_name[i]))
       {
           printf("The player %s, scored %d from %s plays in %s\n", player_name, goals_scored,country_name, team_name );
       }
    }

   fclose(Players);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: you should probably initialize `i` to `0`

Comment: @TaylorFlores I did that now, but is the while loop right ?

Comment: your function calls are a little off

Comment: @TaylorFlores Do you have any suggestions how I can fix them ?

Comment: @Gian,@Yu Hao has any suggestion

Answer (score 2):

`[]` is a type all in itself, you *shouldn't* append `s` or `d` at the its end. All you really have to do is change the format to this:

```
"%[^|] | %d | %[^|] | %[^|]|\n"
```

And consider changing your `while` loop to break when `fscanf` doesn't return `4`.

Here's some working code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define NUM_PLAYERS 20
#define NAME_LENGTH 100
#define COUNTRY_NAME 20

int
main (void)
{
    FILE * Players;
    char player_name [NUM_PLAYERS][NAME_LENGTH] = {0};
    char country_name[NUM_PLAYERS][COUNTRY_NAME] = {0};
    char team_name[NUM_PLAYERS][NAME_LENGTH] = {0};
    int  goals_scored[NUM_PLAYERS] = {0};
    int i = 0, ret = 0;

    Players = fopen("testfile", "r");

    if (Players == NULL)
        {
            printf("File not found.\n");
        }

    else
        {
            for (;;)
                {
                    ret = fscanf(Players, "%[^|] | %d | %[^|] | %[^|]|\n",
                            player_name[i],
                            &goals_scored[i],
                            country_name[i],
                            team_name[i]);

                    if (ret != 4)
                        {
                            printf ("only %d arguments were matched\n", ret);
                            break;
                        }

                    printf("The player %s, scored %d from %s plays in %s\n",
                            player_name[i],
                            goals_scored[i],
                            country_name[i],
                            team_name[i]);
                    i++;
                }
            fclose(Players);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Okay this displays only the first line in my file , and why is the for(;;) like blank, whats the purpose for that .

Comment: @user2512806 the `for(;;)` is usually used when the evaluation occurs somewhere else in the loop that is not in the beginning or end. I tested this on my computer. did the entire code not work or just the format line?

Comment: the code worked, but it printed only the first line not both .

Comment: `printf("The player %s, scored %d from %s plays in %s\n",`
this printf printed only the first line.

Comment: I copied and pasted the code and the file, and both lines print. did you change your input file?

Comment: I copied what you posted, and change the test file to the path where my file is saved.

Answer (score 1):

You never actually consume the "|" characters in between your fields.  Instead you're only reading up until the "|" character.  Try adjusting your format string to something like:

```
"%[^|]|%[^|]d|%[^|]|%[^|]"
```

Comment: yeah I know that, it wasn't going after the first name , okay I will try this

Comment: I didn't downvote this answer, but it's probably cause you don't have an elaborate explanation

Comment: Fair enough.  In any case, your answer was excellent and I have duly upvoted it :)

Answer (score 1):

The `scanf` format `%[^|]s` reads a string of non-`|` characters followed by an `s` character, which can never match (since the next character after the string, if it exists, must be a `|`, not an `s`).  You probably want something more like:

```
while (4 == fscanf(Players, " %99[^|\n]|%d| %19[^|\n]| %99[^|\n]", player_name[i], &goals_scored[i], country_name[i], team_name[i]))
```

Note the additional string size limits to avoid overflowing arrays, and the newlines in the patterns, so that they can't be included in any of the strings (but can appear between strings).

Note also that this will match your second line, but will leave `|Madrit` to be read by the next call to fscanf, so you might want to put

```
fscanf(Players, "%*[\n]%*c");
```

in the loop to read the rest of the line up to the newline and throw it away.

Comment: @Chris Dodd the |Madrit doesnt need to be that way, it needs to be Real Madrit together. My mistake , sorry

Comment: Players = fopen("G:\\COP2220\\Project 5\\Players.txt", "r");
    if (Players == NULL)
    {
        printf("File not found.\n");
    }
    else

    {
        i = 0;
        while (4 == fscanf(Players, " %99[^|\n]|%d| %19[^|\n]| %99[^|\n]", player_name[i], &goals_scored[i], country_name[i], team_name[i]))
      
       {
           printf("The player %s, scored %d from %s plays in %s\n", player_name, goals_scored,country_name, team_name );
       i ++;
       }
       printf("end");
    }

    fclose(Players);
`

Comment: The player Del Piero, scored 2289032 from Italy plays in Juventus
The player Del Piero, scored 2289032 from Italy plays in Juventus
end
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.060 s
Press any key to continue.

Comment: @user2512806: you're missing the `[i]` indexes on the vars in the `printf` line.

Answer (score 0):

Your format scan string is incorrect. The `%[..]` is itself the format specifier, adding the `s` or `d` after it is just taken to be a literal `s` or `d` in the scan string, and not a `%s` or `%d` like you are expecting.

Also, your `printf()` prints out the `goals_scored` address rather than the stored value for the player. You forgot to index the array.

It is possible to get your format scan string to work, but since the last field appears optional, you have some complexity to deal with that case. In the code below, we deal with this by explicitly calling out that the newline should not be part of the last field. Then the `%*c` will discard either the `|` or the `\n` at the end. The space at the end of the scan string allows `fscanf()` to move to the next line in the case that the `|` was discarded.

```
   while (fscanf(Players, " %[^|]|%d|%[^|]|%[^|\n]%*c ",
                 player_name[i], &goals_scored[i], country_name[i], team_name[i]) == 4)
   {
       printf("The player %s, scored %d from %s plays in %s\n",
              player_name, goals_scored[i], country_name, team_name);
   }
```

However, this problem seems ideal for `strtok()`. The advantage is that you have more control over how to deal with each field, and you can get more information about where errors are occurring during a parse of the line.

```
int parse_line (char *buffer,
               char *name, int *goals, char *country, char *team,
               char **rest)
{
    char *tok = strtok(buffer, "|");
    int count = 0;
    while (tok && count < 4) {
        ++count;
        switch (count) {
        case 1: strcpy(name, tok); break;
        case 2: *goals = atoi(tok); break;
        case 3: strcpy(country, tok); break;
        case 4: strcpy(team, tok); break;
        default: break;
        }
        tok = strtok(0, "|");
    }
    *rest = tok;
    return count;
}
```

You would change your code to read in a line of data, and then feed that line to the `parse_line()` function.

```
char buf[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
char *rest;
while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), Players) != 0) {
    parse_line(buf,
               player_name[i], &goals_scored[i], country_name[i], team_name[i],
               &rest);
    printf("The player %s, scored %d from %s plays in %s\n",
           player_name, goals_scored[i], country_name, team_name);
}
```

Comment: I don't know, I am new in C and I haven't seen all this that you have posted, and I dont really understand very well. I was more looking for help in the program I already have. However , thank you very much I appreciate your help .

Comment: @user2512806: Look at the first suggestion. It just fixes your current scan string and `fscanf()` call and your print statement.